# Single instance changing of caption

Tags: captions

I have a setup where I need, for one instance, to make a caption read Equations rather than Equation. Is there a way to do this The code that I have is below

Cheers

```
    \documentclass{scrreprt}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{aliascnt}%Counter and float caption for Equations
    \newaliascnt{eqnfloat}{equation}
    \newfloat{eqnfloat}{h}{eqflts}
    \floatname{eqnfloat}{Equation}
      \newcommand*{\ORGeqnfloat}{}
      \let\ORGeqnfloat\eqnfloat
      \def\eqnfloat{%
      \let\ORIGINALcaption\caption
      \def\caption{%
      \addtocounter{equation}{-1}%
      \ORIGINALcaption
       }%
      \ORGeqnfloat
  }

\begin{document}

{eqnfloat}[!ht]
\begin{eqnarray}
 A=B+C \label{eqn:1}\\
 B=X+Y \label{eqn:2}
\end{eqnarray}
\caption{Some caption}
\labeL{eqn:1+2}
\end{eqnfloat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your 'MWE' contains some errors

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the equations which should be be captioned with 'Equations' with a `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair and use a `\floatname{eqnfloat}{Equations}` statement before starting the floating environment. It will change only for this special group of equations.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{aliascnt}%Counter and float caption for Equations
    \usepackage{caption}
    \newaliascnt{eqnfloat}{equation}
    \newfloat{eqnfloat}{h}{eqflts}
    \floatname{eqnfloat}{Equation}
      \newcommand*{\ORGeqnfloat}{}
      \let\ORGeqnfloat\eqnfloat
      \def\eqnfloat{%
      \let\ORIGINALcaption\caption
      \def\caption{%
      \addtocounter{equation}{-1}%
      \ORIGINALcaption
       }%
      \ORGeqnfloat
}

\begin{document}


\begingroup
\floatname{eqnfloat}{Equations}
\begin{eqnfloat}[!ht]

\begin{eqnarray}
 A=B+C \label{eqn:1}\\
 B=X+Y \label{eqn:2}
\end{eqnarray}
\caption{Some caption}
\label{eqn:1+2}
\end{eqnfloat}

\endgroup


\begin{eqnfloat}[!ht]

\begin{eqnarray}
 A=B+C \label{eqn:3}\\
 B=X+Y \label{eqn:4}
\end{eqnarray}
\caption{Some caption}
\label{eqn:3+4}
\end{eqnfloat}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, Cheers!

Comment: Sorry Christian, How do it get it to then read "Equations 0.1 & 0.2"?

Comment: @Magiclamarshmallow: That's a design flaw of your floating equation environment, it has nothing to do with `\floatname`.

Comment: I got a work around 
              \begingroup
              \floatname{eqnfloat}{Equations \ref{eq:1}\&}
              \begin{eqnfloat}[!ht]
Probably not the best solution, but given its a one off it should be OK I hope